# AJAX call and UPDATE query not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send an `UPDATE` query to my update_divisions.php file via an AJAX call to update a player's division. I have a select box that I can choose the user from and then another select box that I can choose the division that I want to send. I did not include this, but I have an AJAX call that get's information from a php file that shows the usernames and the division they are currently in. That works perfect. So, I am just trying to update the division now. I have php error code on and I do not get any errors for that. I get an error in my network tab after I hit submit to send this of:

Uncaught syntax error...for this line in my AJAX call..

```
"username="+$user,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my full code.

```
try {
//Prepare
if ($division_stmt= $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM team_rankings WHERE user_id=user_id")) {

    $division_stmt->execute();
    $division_stmt->bind_result($division_id, $division_user_id, $division_firstname, $division_username, $division_division, $division_wins, $division_losses); 

    //var_dump($division_stmt);

    if (!$division_stmt) {
        throw new Exception($con->error);
    }

    $division_stmt->store_result();
    echo "<span class='top_bottom_margin'>Select a user to modify their team rank</span>". "<br>";
    echo "<select id = 'member_division'>";
    while ($division_row = $division_stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<option value='{$division_username}' data-username='{$division_username}'>{$division_username}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";


} else {
    echo "<p>There are not any team players yet.</p>";
}
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

            <label>Current Division
                <input type="text" id="current_division">
            </label>
            <form name="update_group_form" action="" type="POST">   
                <select name="division_name">
                    <option value="1">East</option>
                    <option value="2">West</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="division_update_button">
            </form>
```

AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#update_group_form").on("change", function(){
            $user = this.value;
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "update_division.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                "username="+$user,
                division_name: $(this).find('select[name="group_id"]').val()
                },
                success: function(text){ 
                     alert(data);
            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown )
            {
              // alert on an http error 
              alert( textStatus +  errorThrown );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP file - update_division.php

```
$update_division = $_POST['division_name'];


$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE division FROM team_rankings WHERE username = :user");
    if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User Group update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('i', $update_division)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Group update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('User Group update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

Comment: In the ajax-code, maybe change `"username="+$user,` into `"username": $user,`? (or even `username: $user,`). I think all the values in a javascript object need a field name.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to merge php and jquery as I can see.

Try to change this:

```
 $user = this.value;
```

For this:

```
var user = this.value;
```

And this:

```
"username="+$user,
```

For this:

```
"username="+user,
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: I had ` $user = this.value;` and `"username="+$user,` in my AJAX call to my `SELECT` query and it worked perfectly to get the usernames and to change the results per username I selected.

Comment: Did you can try to print with console.log($user) and check it with firebug after you submit for reproduce your error and get more information?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to print out results with JS in the console.

Comment: Ok, its too easy. Put this: console.log($user); just after your $user declaration variable. Then save your file and open your Google Chrome.Then just press to F5 to reload your files (.js) and then press your F12 button and click to Console tab.

Submit your update and just watch the result.

Comment: Nothing comes up. It dies at this `"username="+$user,` and I put the console log under it.